# Iterative column max stats from dataframe pivot table and indexing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, pivot-table

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Lets consider the following data example:

```
dfexample = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['apple','red','a',100],
                              ['apple','red','b',100],
                              ['apple','red','c',80],
                              ['apple','red','d',70],
                              ['apple','red','e',60],
                              ['apple','red','f',50],
                              ['apple','yellow','a',99],
                              ['apple','yellow','b',98],
                              ['apple','yellow','c',97],
                              ['apple','yellow','d',96],
                              ['apple','yellow','e',95],
                              ['apple','yellow','f',94],
                              ['apple','green','a',10],
                              ['apple','green','b',9],
                              ['apple','green','c',8],
                              ['apple','green','d',7],
                              ['apple','green','e',6],
                              ['apple','green','f',5]
                              ]),
                              columns=['fruit','colour','cat','score'])
                 
dfexample = dfexample.astype({"score": float})
```

I can pivot the data to cast the cat to unique columns:

```
pivotexample = dfexample.pivot_table(index = ['fruit','colour'],
                         columns = ['cat'],
                         values = ['score'],
                         fill_value = 0).swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(1)

print(pivotexample)
```

Output:

```
cat              a     b     c     d     e     f
             score score score score score score
fruit colour                                    
apple green     10     9     8     7     6     5
      red      100   100    80    70    60    50
      yellow    99    98    97    96    95    94
```

Can the max value for each cat column be calculated iteratively (looped over cat column a -> f) so that the highest value is returned with the fruit_colour index, but not a index picked earlier in the loop.

From top example I would like to return:

cat, (max)score, fruit_colour

a, 100, apple_red    (max value)

b,  98, apple_yellow (98 max value because 100(apple_red) was picked as previous highest index)

c,   8, apple_green  (8 max value because 97(apple_yellow) and 80(apple_red) previous highest indexes)

Manual Excel view:

[Excel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vDhT.png)

Thank you very much for looking.

Regards

#####################################################################

Answer as provided edited:

```
def calc_mystats(dx, picked_colors_):
    dx = dx.sort_values(by=['score'], ascending=False)
    for index, row in dx.iterrows():
        if row['colour'] not in picked_colors_:
            picked_colors_.append(row['colour'])
            return pd.Series([row['cat'], row['score'], row['fruit'] + "_" + row['colour']], index=['cat','(max)score', 'fruit_color'])    

picked_colors = ['none']
print(dfexample.groupby('cat').apply(calc_mystats, picked_colors))

print(picked_colors)
```

output:

```
     cat  (max)score   fruit_color
cat                               
a      a        99.0  apple_yellow
b      b         9.0   apple_green
c    NaN         NaN           NaN
d    NaN         NaN           NaN
e    NaN         NaN           NaN
f    NaN         NaN           NaN
['none', 'red', 'yellow', 'green']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Panda's `groupy` ([docs][1]) function instead to generate statistics iteratively over a data frame's columns. First I would group-by the column that I am interested in (`cat` in your case here) and then apply a row function for calculating some statistics over the rows in the group. Here's how I would do it.

Here's the function which calculates the `max_score` for each `cat` identical to what you described in your question:

```
def calc_mystats(dx, picked_colors_):
dx = dx.sort_values(by=['score'], ascending=False)
for index, row in dx.iterrows():
    if row['colour'] not in picked_colors_:
        picked_colors_.append(row['colour'])
        return pd.Series([row['cat'], row['score'], row['fruit'] + "_" + row['colour']], index=['cat','(max)score', 'fruit_color'])
```

Then I would perform the actual groupy pandas operation and apply the function described above.

```
picked_colors = []
print(dfexample.groupby('cat').apply(calc_mystats, picked_colors))
```

Note that the a list `picked_colors` is passed to our function `calc_mystats` to maintain a record of colors chosen so as to not choose the same color twice.

Here is your final output (which is a dataframe)

```
     cat  (max)score   fruit_color
cat                               
a      a       100.0     apple_red
b      b        98.0  apple_yellow
c      c         8.0   apple_green
d    NaN         NaN           NaN
e    NaN         NaN           NaN
f    NaN         NaN           NaN
```

You may need to process the results from the after the `groupby` and `apply` operations. For instance in your case you can use `dropna()`

References: [1]: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Thanks for a brilliant answer @raghu.tjm.

Comment: I added your solution to the question.  Just one question, when I execute the code, it seems to drop the first index, i.e apple_red in this case.  I tried in on another datatable and the same seems to happen.  I checked the contents of picked_color and they all seem to present.  Regards

Comment: I just checked the code and ran this again. It shouldn't drop the `index`. Could you try running the code again? I cleaned up some stuff

Comment: removed `df_out`. that shouldn't be your final output. Your output should be `print(dfexample.groupby('cat').apply(calc_mystats, picked_colors))`

Comment: Thanks @raghu.tjm

Comment: I edited the question with your updated code.  Unfortunetly it still drops the first index "red" in this case when I run it...  I even tried to put a placeholder "none" in the picked_colors as you can see, but it didn't make any difference.  Is my indentation in the function correct?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah i think the only explanation is that your indentation is off. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/raghumulukutla/c3af65b3f208e094f9ac5c73a73a0358